# Extracting contents of archived files in place using 7-Zip and PowerShell

Tags: powershell, 7zip, lzw

I want to extract all *.Z files in place in their current directories (7-Zip support LZW/UNIX compression).

I can't figure out why this is not working. I know how to use PowerShell to recursively get a full path of a filename and directory in which file resides. I also know how to use 7-zip to extract a file in place. But trying to put these two together is not working. Here's what I have:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.Z | foreach ($_) {7z.exe e $_.FullName -o$_.Directory}
```

I also tried:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.Z | foreach ($_) {7z.exe e $_.FullName -o$($_.Directory)}
```

and

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.Z | foreach ($_) {7z.exe e $_.FullName -o${_.Directory}}
```

This is getting the files I want by `FullName`, and `Directory` is the correct path ([no space between the o and directory is how 7-zip expects the output directory](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/output_dir.htm)). However, it keeps trying to output the file to the .Z path rather than the directory. I know it is right if I do

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.Z | Select Directory
```

that is where I want it to go.

I assume the issue was having no space but not sure why it would get same directory. I even manually defined a variable and passed that with no problems.

So the issue is 7-zip saying no files to process when I want to output to same directory but not sure why, and it seems `Directory` variable not being passed but file name again which makes no sense. Sample output per file:

```
7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 226 bytes (1 KiB)

Extracting archive: E:\Files\2014\more_cowbell\myfancyunixcompresseddocument.txt.Z
--
Path = E:\Files\2014\more_cowbell\myfancyunixcompresseddocument.txt.Z
Type = Z


No files to process
Everything is Ok

Files: 0
Size:       0
Compressed: 226
```

It works fine if I specify one specific output directory (no variable), but I want them extracted in place due to many subdirectories and conflicting file names between them.

I want to extract all *.Z files in place in their current directories (7-Zip support LZW/UNIX compression).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-o` parameter should be inside a doublequoted string with `$($var)` for variables:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.z | %{ 7z e $_.FullName "-o$($_.Directory)"}
```

Comment: It may be worth adding a `-File` to the `Get-ChildItem` command to restrict it to files only.